# populate worksheet from excel table

Tags: excel, vba

I have been asked to remake the excel workbook to index where we keep the items.
I have an excel sheet with a table ( excel table) that contains the information.

If the there the value in column 6 ="10" then that means the item is in box 10.
then I need to get the right shelve, this is found by the numbers in column 7 (shelve) and 8 (rack). subsequently the information about the item has to be put in another sheet which gives a visual representation of the box.

I am struggling to get the desired result, does anyone have some suggestions?
[image]

```
Sub box()
Dim rng As Range

For x = 1 To 12
Set rng = Sheets("Register").ListObject("Table1").Range(x, 8).Value

If Range("Table1").ListObject.Range(x, 6).Value = "10" Then
If Range("Table1").ListObject.Range(x, 7).Value = "1" Then
Sheets("box 10").Range(3, rng).Value = Range("Table1").ListObject.Range(x, 2).Value & Range("Table1").ListObject.Range(x, 3)

End If
End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: column designation would be helpful, but i'll take a look at your problem

Comment: What is that "box 10"? A simple range (inside the border)? If so, on which row/column should "box 10" label exist? It should be good to show us more such boxes. Are they positioned vertically or horizontally? Then, a range cannot be set as a `Value`... Looking to your code, should they be vertically positioned and the respective box can be found on B:B, row `x`? A separate sheet should exist for such a pseudo box?

Comment: is "box10" a individual new worksheet? or in this worksheet? because of `Sheet("box10")`

Comment: I edited the picture. 

Yes the visual representation is on another sheet. it is indeed nothing more than a border around the area to make a virtual box.

Comment: On which row does "rack" exist and when which column does "shelve" exist? Your code does not make much sense from many points of view and because of that it cannot be helpful...

Comment: The information of the shelve is under column G, the rack is under column H.

The box is the area that I have been asked to populate with the information based on the designated location. 
as for the code all I could think of was to go with if statements for each box, each number in the row and each number in the shelve ( which I am sure is unnecessary)

Comment: **This is obvious**, but **were from to start counting in the BOX SHEET**, **where the value to be returned**? In your picture is row 14, column C:C. I do not think this is what you want...

Comment: well if I can populate the box in the example then I can make it work for another sheet with a different reference column and row. 

for box 10 It currently starts from C3 (shelve 1 and rack 1)

Comment: Then, try testing the code I posted. I made the code to have the above row and column configurable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will iterate in the table `DataBodyRange` and build a sheet name obtained by concatenation of "Box " with value in table column 6 (in your workbook). If such a sheet does not exist,  a warning message is sent and stops the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub box()
 Dim boxVal As String, tbl As ListObject, shBox As Worksheet, rngRef As Range, x As Long
 Dim shelvNo As Long, rackNo As Long
 Dim iRow As Long:   iRow = 1  ' row where "rack" exist
 Dim iCol As Long:    iCol = 1 'column letter where "rack" exists (C:C)

 Set tbl = Sheets("Register").ListObjects("Table1")
 For x = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count  'on the frist row there are ABC, ABC etc.
    If tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 1) = "" Then Exit For
    boxVal = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 6).Value
    On Error Resume Next
     Set shBox = Sheets("Box " & boxVal) 'set the sheet of the appropriate box  'set the sheet of the appropriate box
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "No sheet named """ & "box " & tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 6).Value & """ exists" & vbCrLf & _
                "Please, create it and run the code again!": Exit Sub
     End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set rngRef = shBox.Cells(iRow, iCol)
     shelvNo = iRow + 1 + tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 7).Value
     rackNo = iCol + tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 8).Value - 1
     rngRef.Offset(shelvNo, rackNo).Value = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 2).Value & " " & tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(x, 3).Value
 Next x
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: I get : "Object doesn't support this property or method". and when I open the vba it highlights this part `Set tbl = Sheets("Register").ListObject("Table1")`

Comment: @user17269242 This only means that there is no table named "Table1" in  `Sheets("Register")`.  Or such a sheet does not exist, neither... Did you try testing **your code**?

Comment: @user17269242 Do you understand how your or my code works? For instance, your code uses `Range("Table1").ListObject.Range(x, 6).Value = "10"`, but this value is in the fifth column. You also use `Sheets("Register").ListObject("Table1").Range(x, 8).Value`, which cannot be even seen in your picture. I tried **deducing** what you want, according to what I could understand/deduce looking to the picture you posted... If not something confidential, can you share the workbook you work on? It looks that explaining in words of what you want accomplishing is difficult...

Comment: I have another code that used table1 on the (active sheet)
but it is definitely on the sheet named Register

Comment: I will modify my workbook so that i can share it

Comment: But is the table in discussion named "Table1"? You can send it to my personal mail (in my profile), or using a transfer site. [This one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used...

Comment: Alright, I sent you an email.
Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: @user17269242 OK. I will look at it now.

Comment: @user17269242 You must understand that the code needs complete consistency in the way of building the sheets to receive information. Then, when you show us a table, it should look like the one you intend using. Yours misses a column. I will adapt the above code in a way to work for your case. After that, I will send you back the processed workbook.

Comment: @user17269242 Please, test the updated code. I also sent back the workbook with the involved sheets as they should look and working code. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: it works beautifully (I just removed the +1 and -1 in the last few lines). Thank you again ;)

Comment: @user17269242 If you keep the "box x" sheets as I set them in the testing file, no need of that modification...